# Set Focus inside the text box of a tool strip

Tags: c#, winforms

I put a toolstrip on the form, added some controls to it such as buttons, labels and a text box...now I want the text input focus be inside abd blinking in the text box of that toolstrip,

I tried with these two commands in a form_load evet but didn't work:

```
toolStripTextBox1.Focus();
// or
toolStripTextBox1.Select();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work or not, but try focusing the tool strip itself, and then focus the tool strip textbox.

Comment: Not sure why you got all these downvotes.  I upvoted you, because I've hit the exact same issue, and this post solved my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the event handler for your form's `Shown` event and you can try with this code:

```
static bool first = true;
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (first)
       {
            toolStripTextBox1.Focus();
            first = false;
       }
}
```

Comment: awesome. It fixed my other focus question that I had asked and you had answered too .

Comment: @BDotA Glad I could help. I'm sure you know that other answers also work for this particular question.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
Me.ActiveControl = toolStripTextBox1.Control
```

Comment: His control is not TextBox2.Control that will generate an Error..it's TextBox1

Comment: Can you please provide solution in C#? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing the following

```
Me.ActiveControl = toolStripTextBox1.Control
```